# SQL combine count and sum in distinct query

Tags: count, sql-server-2012, sum, distinct

I have some issues creating a query which should show various statistics for departments - number of cases (new, active, closed, aborted), targets projected and actual (number and value), number of unbalanced cases and amounts.

Part of the code which gives a good picture of what I need is below. "u" table is a CTE where I dumped joins from four tables (Cases , users, notes and payments).

Some of them are sum, subtraction, multiplication or their combination.

**(1)** Is there a way to not to repeat same count just so I can do subtraction in next column?

Performance is not an issue - statistic is needed daily, so I can queue it to run at midnight, but code bloats quickly with repetitions and I'm not at all sure it is truly distinct, but I have to have some sort of final version of the query before I can start comparing it against raw data.

Also, at this point I'm stumped:

```
DECLARE @StartExDate datetime 
DECLARE @EndExDate datetime
declare @ThisWeekNow int = 0

SET @StartExDate =
     (SELECT(CONVERT(DATETIME, (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))))))
SET @EndExDate =
     (SELECT(CONVERT(DATETIME, (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))))))
SET @ThisWeekNow = (SELECT DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()));
WITH u
as
(SELECT tt.team, tt.target, m.client, m.case, m.Created, m.AC_Manager, m.Casetype,
m.Supervisor, m.CAc_Balance, m.OAc_Balance, m.DAc_Balance,m.Notes, m.termsSent,
m.TermsRec, m.Complete, n.Note, clt.Costs, clt.VAT, clt.Type, us.UserCode, us.Manager
    from users us
    inner join tt
    on tt.team = us.Manager
    inner join m
    on us.Usercode = m.Ac_Manager
    inner join n
    ON m.client = n.client and m.Case = n.case
    inner join clt
    on m.Client = clt.Client_Code and m.case = clt.case_No
    where m.Created > '2014-03-01 00:00:000'
    )
Select distinct
     tt.Team
    ,tt.Target
    ,(Select count(*) from users us where Us.Manager = tt.team) as 'Team Target'
    ,(Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.case as varchar)) 
      from u where tt.team = u.Manager and
      Complete = 0 and u.Created > @StartExDate and u.Created < @EndExDate
     ) as 'New'
    ,(Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.Case as varchar))
      from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 0) as ' All Live'
    ,(Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.Case as varchar))
      from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 0
             and u.TC_Received is not null) as 'Unsigned'
    ,(Select a - n from
       (Select 
        (Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.Case as varchar))
         from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 0) as a
        ,(Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.Case as varchar))
          from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 0 
          and u.TC_Received is not null) as n
     ) x    ) as 'Worked'
    ,(Select tt.target - (Select a - n from 
       (Select 
        (Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.Case as varchar)) 
         from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 0) as a
       ,(Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.Case as varchar))
        from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 0 
                and u.TC_Rec is not null) as n
       ) x ) p  ) as 'Free capacity'
    ,(Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.Case as varchar))
      from u
      where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 0
      and patindex('%Signed%',u.note) > 0 ) as 'Signed'
    ,(Select (SUM(u.costs)+SUM(u.VAT)) 
      from u 
      where tt.team = u.Manager and u.Complete = 0
      and patindex('%Signed%',u.note) > 0  and u.TC_Received  is not null
     ) as 'Actual Income'
    ,(Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.Case as varchar)) 
      from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 0
       and patindex('%Aborted%',u.note) > 0 ) as 'Aborts'
    ,(Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.Case as varchar))
      from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 1 ) as 'Completions'
    ,(Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.Case as varchar))
      from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 1 and u.OAc_Balance > 0
     ) as 'Office Balances'
    ,(Select sum (distinct u.OAc_Balance)
      from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 1 ) as 'OB Amount'
    ,(Select count(distinct u.Client+cast(u.Case as varchar))
      from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 1 and u.CAc_Balance > 0
    ) as 'Client Balances'
    ,(Select sum (distinct u.CAc_Balance)
      from u where tt.team = u.Manager and Complete = 1) as 'CB Amount'
from tt
join u
on tt.Team = u.Manager
group by tt.Team, tt.Target, u.Usercode
order by tt.Team
```

This whole procedure is supposed to give us a summary of work being done in company and additional statistics. And looking like that:

```
Team|Target|Team Members|New| All Live|Unsigned|Worked|Free Capacity|Signed|Actual Income|Aborts|Completions|Office Balances|OB Amount|Client Balances|CB Amount|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA |   360|           8|  2|      247|     223|    24|          336|    71|      85434.6|     4|        165|             22|  1340.84|             87|205777.58|
BBB |   420|           9|  3|      536|     437|    99|          321|   162|    185089.42|     4|        698|             74|   7293.2|            310|942835.87|
CCC |   420|           7|  0|      439|     355|    84|          336|   116|     178517.4|     6|        498|             64|   8604.2|            264|109842.76|
DDD |   420|           9|  0|      725|     290|   435|          -15|   189|      61415.2|     7|        591|             64|  7580.54|            256|569165.07|
EEE |   420|           6|  1|      423|     302|   121|          299|   100|    105229.38|     2|        606|             42|  7679.66|            382|126168.31|
FFF |   420|           8|  1|      498|     450|    48|          372|   123|    124665.68|     3|        367|             36|   3947.7|            257| 93294.52|
GGG |   420|           8|  2|      467|     406|    61|          359|   105|     119822.4|    97|        356|             43|  2143.68|            140|215389.32|
HHH |     1|           1|  0|      186|     150|    36|          -35|    65|        82878|     0|         81|             22|   2255.2|             84|  6863.74|
III |   360|           7|  1|      527|     454|    73|          287|   158|    165513.58|     6|        417|             42|  3242.08|            160|102729.61|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total:
```

Columns 3 through 6 are counts, column seven is Subtraction (Targets-Unsigned), Free capacity is subtraction again: Target-Worked, Actual Income is sum of values for each case (and should be counting same rows as in column Signed) etc. I also need to insert percents columns as well, but this is the question number 1: how to reuse the data *(that is: counted in previous column used as argument in arithmetic operation in current)*?

Quick count in excel shows every row of column with value is way to big. And the query exec time is already around 100 seconds. Not an issue yet, but would like to lower it.

So question **(2)**: *Is there a way to sum same rows as ones counted in previous column with distinct string*

Most of the convolutions in procedure would be unnecessary had SQL could parse 'WHERE ( x or y) and ( x1 or x2 or x3)' in anything resembling logic.

I don't know if its a good idea to post sample of U, as it is join of four tables... So - big - sample would have to have several hundred rows at least. Sanitizing that data is a pain.

Comment: Would it be possible to post some sample data (table tt and u) as input and what your expected output should be. This will help others to help you.

Comment: OK, will do that. But fair warning: it will be big. good idea though - maybe I'm doing something wrong.